# C++ split string line by line using std::regex

Tags: c++, regex

I use this function to split the string:

```
std::vector<std::string> splitString(const std::string& stringToSplit, const std::string& regexPattern)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    const std::regex rgx(regexPattern);
    std::sregex_token_iterator iter(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), rgx, -1);

    for (std::sregex_token_iterator end; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        result.push_back(iter->str());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, if I want to split a string line by line (say, I have read a file content into a single variable), I do this:

```
auto vec = splitString(fileContent, "\\n");
```

On Windows, I get this:

```
line 1 \r
line 2 \r
```

This happens because Windows line ending is determined with `\r\n`. I have tried to use `$`, but again without success. What is the right way to capture line endings in Windows, too?

Comment: Use `[\\r\\n]+`. `auto vec = splitString(fileContent, "[\\r\\n]+");`

Comment: Would it work in Linux, OS X, iOS, Android?

Comment: Since the `\r` and `\n` are line separators, I think it will run on all OSes.

Comment: Please let me know if the regex works for you, then I could post it as answer.

Comment: @Narek: Yes it will work for these systems (all use LF as newline). But unfortunately it will not work on the ATARI 800 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux/Unix, OS X, iOS, Android OSes, line separators are either `\r`, or `\n`, or a combination of them. So, the most efficient way to capture them all is placing into a character class and use the `+` quantifier.

Thus, `[\\r\\n]+` should "do the trick":

```
auto vec = splitString(fileContent, "[\\r\\n]+");
```

**EDIT**:

As  @FabioFracassi mentions, this will remove empty lines.
If empty lines should be preserved in the output, you can use

```
auto vec = splitString(fileContent, "(?:\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)");
```

The alternative list is starting with the longest option, since regular expressions are processed from left to right (at least, by default).

Comment: won't that have inconsistent behavior on (consecutive) empty lines?

Comment: That depends on whether empty lines must be present in the resulting array. It is true that in case empty lines should be preserved, the regex must be `"(?:\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)"`.